# could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.asciidoctor.convert:org.asciidoctor.convert.gradle.plugin:2.2.1'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I made a gradle spring project setup at spring initializr, After opening the project in IDE, this error occurred. It shows like plugin not found.

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.asciidoctor.convert', version: '2.2.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.asciidoctor.convert:org.asciidoctor.convert.gradle.plugin:2.2.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:238)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$3(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:168)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:212)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:206)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequests(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:166)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:101)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:117)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:378)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:359)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:383)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:383)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:359)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:762)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:153)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$1(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$9(StateTransitionController.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:334)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:50)
```

could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.asciidoctor.convert:org.asciidoctor.convert.gradle.plugin:2.2.1'

Answer (score 0):

I went to mvnrepository.com looked for version available.

Replacing
 `id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '2.2.1'`
with
`id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '2.4.0'`
solved the issue.